# Using CAST() and resulting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do a SELECT for concatenating 2 columns in MSSQL 2008R2.

> COALESCE(SeriePolita, '') + COALESCE(CAST(NumarPolita AS numeric), '') as NrSeriePolita

Both SeriePolita and NumarPolita are NVARCHAR. The difference between them is that SeriePolita contains text and NumarPolita only number.
I need to convert NumarPolita from 0008838630 to 8838630.
As you ca see in the code line, i used CAST() for NumarPolita but i get this message:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AAA' to data type int.

Is there another way to covert a NVARCHAR to INT/NUMERIC?
Thank you!

Comment: You must filter out rows with non-numeric character first.

Comment: how to convert this type of value  'AAA'  into numeric

Comment: You can't. Since it's not numeric. You can only `CAST` to another data type if the `CONVERSION` is valid.

Comment: Just FYI, in `SQL Server 2012 +`, all you have to do is `CONCAT(SeriePolita, NumarPolita)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it back to NVARCHAR to concatenate it, since concatenation of nvarchar with numeric is not possible:

```
COALESCE(SeriePolita, '') + COALESCE(CAST(CAST(NumarPolita AS numeric) AS NVARCHAR), '') as NrSeriePolita
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression and [`ISNUMERIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx):

```
SELECT

  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(NumarPolita)
      THEN COALESCE(SeriePolita, '') + COALESCE(CAST(NumarPolita AS numeric), '')
    ELSE ''
  END AS NrSeriePolita

  FROM ...
```

Alternatively, if you only need the records where this conversion is possible, you can use `ISNUMERIC` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Never suggest `Isnumeric` function to solve this kind of problem. It has way too many drawbacks